# Must the DLL be in the lib folder in a nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, jwt

I tried to download the latest version of this nuget:

JSON Web Token Handler For the Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 3.0.1

but its not installing correctly in my project.

In my Visual Studio solution, I looked in the folder:

```
\packages\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.3.0.1\
```

and the DLLs exist, but they are not within the **lib** folder. They are in the package's root.

When I try to install it in my VS project, it says its been installed, but no project references are added.

I think its broken. Can anyone confirm that a nuget **must** have a **lib** folder and the DLLs must be within the **lib** folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just pushed a new version out, 3.0.2, that fixes this issue. Please try to update the NuGet and let me know if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I duplicated the folder structure of the previous package (version 3.0.0) and got it working. I left two messages with the author a week ago.